# How do I pause the command progression until a reply has been received

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a mafia game bot, at first I need to ask the mafia who he wants to murder, and then proceed with the rest of the game, how can I do that?

My code:

```js
let filter = (m) => m.author.id === Mafia.id;
MafiaChannel.send("Who do you want to kill?").then(() => {
    MafiaChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ["time"],
    })
        .then((message) => {
            message = message.first();
            if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `${Innocent1}`) {
                MafiaChannel.send(`You killed ${Innocent1}`);
            } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `${Doctor}`) {
                MafiaChannel.send(`You killed ${Doctor}`);
            } else {
                MafiaChannel.send("Invalid Input");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    MafiaChannel.delete();
                }, 5000);
            }
        })
        .catch((collected) => {
            MafiaChannel.send("Timeout");
        });
});
```

There is code that runs after this, but doesn't wait until the reply has been sent by the mafia, How can I make it pause until a reply is registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to go about that is to put all of the code succeeding it into a function and call that function within the `.then`.

```
// Initialize the function that will run after the code is finished.
// We add an argument for the message that was collected, in case we want to do .reply() on it.
// We make it async for the same reason
async function afterReply(msg) {
    console.log("Finished!")
}

let filter = (m) => m.author.id === Mafia.id;
MafiaChannel.send("Who do you want to kill?").then(() => {
    MafiaChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ["time"],
    })
        .then(async (message) => {
            message = message.first();

            // Add some awaits here to make sure that the replies are sent before running the afterReply() function
            if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `${Innocent1}`) {
                await MafiaChannel.send(`You killed ${Innocent1}`);
            } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `${Doctor}`) {
                await MafiaChannel.send(`You killed ${Doctor}`);
            } else {
                await MafiaChannel.send("Invalid Input");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    MafiaChannel.delete();
                }, 5000);
            }

            afterReply(message)
        })
        .catch((collected) => {
            MafiaChannel.send("Timeout");
        });
});
```

`Finished!` should print to the console after all of the replies have finished. But this method is hacky and wouldn't work so well with multiple collectors (in case you have more after this block). Plus it looks ugly, so I'll give you another method using async/await that is a bit more complicated. But I'll try my best to explain what is happening in the code

```
let filter = (m) => m.author.id === Mafia.id;
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

// First lets send our message asking who they want to kill
await MafiaChannel.send("Who do you want to kill?")

// The try/catch block is important.
// Because we aren't using a .then and .catch we have to
// properly handle a promise rejection using the try/catch.
try {
    // Now we initialize our message collector. This one uses await as opposed to .then,
    // but the effect is pretty much the same. The code will wait until we get a message
    // or will reject the promise if the time is up
    let collected = await MafiaChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ["time"],
    })

    let response = collected.first();

    if (response.content.toUpperCase() == `${Innocent1}`) {
        await MafiaChannel.send(`You killed ${Innocent1}`);
    } else if (response.content.toUpperCase() == `${Doctor}`) {
        await MafiaChannel.send(`You killed ${Doctor}`);
    } else {
        await MafiaChannel.send("Invalid Input");
        // Replace the settimeout with a sleep function to halt the code. Settimeout is non-blocking and will not halt the code, so its useful to use the sleep function in times where you want a settimeout that blocks.
        // However I don't know if you want the rest of the code to wait the full 5 seconds for the deletion to occur before running the rest.
        // Do whatever suits your purposes. If you want the rest of the code to wait until the deletion occurs, keep the sleep function. If you want the rest of the code to run at the same time as the countdown to the deletion, then keep the settimeout.
        // Also I can't help but notice that you do MafiaChannel.delete().. Is this a typo or do you actually intend to delete the entire channel if given an invalid input?
        await sleep(5000)
        await MafiaChannel.delete();
    }
} catch (e) {
    return MafiaChannel.send("Timeout");
}

console.log("Finished!")
```

`Finished!` should be printed to the console after the replies are sent. This method is prettier and more readable in my opinion, but also more complicated since it makes heavy use of async/await. You also get the benefit of being able to put the code that's supposed to run afterwards under the try/catch block, which is much more readable than a function that has code meant to run later above the collector

I recommend that you look at [async/await](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), they're really useful for solving problems like these and are important concepts in JavaScript. I haven't tested the code so I'm not entirely sure that it works, but give it a try and let me know if you have any more questions or concerns.